# Bare essentials (assemblies) to be referenced for an empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project with EF 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

There's a ton of DLL's and javascript files in the ASP.NET MVC 4 project templates. Add an EDM to that and you've got some more.

Which of these contstitute the bare minimum required by an empty ASP.NET MVC project that requires an Entity Framework 4 generated EDM?

I'd like to remove the extraneous DLL references and javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful way to get rid of the stuff you don't need is to open the Nuget Package manager screen, bring up the list of installed packages, and remove the ones you're not interested in. The benefit being that you can read a pretty good description of what you're removing before removing it.